# Problema com parâmetro

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, pdo

Opa. Estou fazendo um código utilizando PHP para manipulação do banco de dados desta forma:

```
try {
        $bancodedados = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `p00_produto`");
        $bancodedados->execute();
        if ($bancodedados->rowCount()!=0){
            ?>
            <table style="border: 1px solid black;">
                <tr>
                    <th>Código</th>
                    <th style="width:50%">Descrição</th>
                    <th style="width:25%">Preço</th>
                    <th> % Imposto</th>
                </tr>
            <?php
            /* INICIO DO LOOP DE SELECT */
            foreach ($bancodedados as $row){
                echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<th>".$row["p00_codigo"]."</th>";
                    echo "<th>".$row["p00_descricao"]."</th>";
                    echo "<th>".$row["p00_preco"]."</th>";
                    echo "<th>".$row["p00_imposto"]."</th>";
                    echo "<th><button class='myBtn' onclick='edit_prod(".$row['p00_descricao'].")'>Editar</button></th>";
                echo "</tr>";   
            }
```

Dessa forma, criam-se uma várias linhas com as informações dos produtos e o botão para editar essas mesmas informações. Porém, estou com um problema que quando eu aperto esse botão e chamo a minha função **edit_prod** do Javascript, o dado inserido apresenta o erro de indefinido.

Função do Javascript:

```
async function edit_prod(desc) {
console.log(desc);
```

}

Rodando o código, obtenho essa saída no console:

**caught ReferenceError: teste is not defined
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (produtos.php:23:136)
onclick @ produtos.php:23**

No console do navegador a linha referida está:

```
<tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>teste</th>
    <th>12.00</th>
    <th>10.30</th>
    <th><button class='myBtn' onclick='edit_prod(teste)'>Editar</button></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>testando</th>
    <th>9.00</th>
    <th>10.00</th>
    <th><button class='myBtn' onclick='edit_prod(testando)'>Editar</button></th>
</tr>
```

Sim, todo esse código está na mesma linha. O erro se da na primeira letra 'T' do primeiro botão.

O erro também só ocorre quando a informação é um texto, quando utilizo, por exemplo, a linha **p00_codigo** a informação é exposta corretamente.

Sei que provavelmente é um erro básico de jogo de caracteres ou aspas, mas estou iniciando meus estudos com javascript e não tenho total noção da ocorrência. Desde já agradeço por quem se disponibilizar a ajudar.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Olá, este erro está ocorrendo pois você passa as variáveis `teste` e `testando` no `onclick` dos dois botões. Essa duas variáveis que não estão definidas no contexto/escopo do JavaScript. Por isso ocorre o erro:

`teste is not defined` = "teste" não é definido

O erro só é mostrado na primeira ocorrência pois o navegador executa o código JavaScript de cima para baixo. Quando ele encontra um erro, geralmente para de executar o restante do código. Caso você exclua a linha problemática, o seu código ainda irá apresentar um erro, só que neste caso seria: `testando is not defined`

Eu não entendi completamente o que você deseja passar como um argumento da função, mas creio que você esteja tentando a descrição que é o texto que está no segundo `<th>` de cada `<tr>`. Se for o caso, você deve passar a string "teste" ou "testando" como argumento da função. Você pode fazer isso colocando o texto entre aspas.

Ou seja, em seu código PHP, o `foreach` deve escrever o código com essas aspas na linha especificada, ficaria da seguinte forma:

```php
foreach ($bancodedados as $row){
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>".$row["p00_codigo"]."</th>";
        echo "<th>".$row["p00_descricao"]."</th>";
        echo "<th>".$row["p00_preco"]."</th>";
        echo "<th>".$row["p00_imposto"]."</th>";
        echo "<th><button class='myBtn' onclick='edit_prod(\"".$row['p00_descricao']."\")'>Editar</button></th>";
    echo "</tr>";   
}
```

Seu HTML ficaria dessa forma:

```html
<tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>teste</th>
    <th>12.00</th>
    <th>10.30</th>
    <th><button class='myBtn' onclick='edit_prod("teste")'>Editar</button></th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>testando</th>
    <th>9.00</th>
    <th>10.00</th>
    <th><button class='myBtn' onclick='edit_prod("testando")'>Editar</button></th>
</tr>
```